# How can I fine tune the any generative model? Autotrain

Tags: machine-learning, training-data, stable-diffusion, fine-tuning

How can I fine tune Realistic_Vision_V6.0_B1_noVAE model and generate my own images? Here is the huggingface [link](https://huggingface.co/SG161222/Realistic_Vision_V6.0_B1_noVAE).

I have used autotrain on stable diffusion base xl model. But using it on this Realistic Vision model seems not quite right. Model generates bad images.

> autotrain dreambooth --model SG161222/Realistic_Vision_V6.0_B1_noVAE
> --image-path input_images/ --prompt "photo of maha person" --resolution 1024 --batch-size 1 --num-steps 500 --mixed-precision fp16 --gradient-accumulation 4 --lr 1e-4 --project-name
> realistic-vision

this gives me pytorch_lora_weights.safetensors file and I use this to generate my own images.
pipe.load_lora_weights("model/", weight_name="pytorch_lora_weights.safetensors")

Is this correct technique of fine-tuning Realistic_Vision_V6.0_B1_noVAE model? Or any model like stable diffusion?